# How to disable versioning in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I know sometimes it's a good feature, but if i need to store large amount of data, it's unnecessary other "meta-data" around the data itself.

Is there any way how to disable versioning in CouchDB, or do i need to use different DB engine, like Mongo?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Versioning isn't a **feature** of CouchDB **it is a core function** of the way it works writing the data to the disk and preforms replication conflict resolution with other nodes. It is **not** a history mechanism.

It is very unfortunate that there isn't a better term than `version` for referring to the previous copies of the documents. Because `version` to most developers means something `historical` that is warehoused. That isn't what it is intended to be used as at all in CouchDB.

It is plastered all over the CouchDB documentation to **not rely** on previous *versions* as backups or a versioning system, that they can potentially disappear at anytime, because they are used for replication conflict detection mainly. But the simple fact is this isn't a **feature** it is just how CouchDB works.

The only way to remove the past versions is to [compact](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction) the database periodically. In the current version of CouchDB this can be enabled with a script that hooks into document updates and fires off semi-automatic compaction based on a high water mark threshold. Usually this is done manually after a large set of documents are updated in a batch a you know that this might be beneficial from an application specific standpoint.

**That said, if you aren't updating documents no history is generated and this is not needed.**

Comment: +1. Radek, perhaps ask yourself: is this a premature optimization? Why am I avoiding CouchDB revisions? Because it doesn't *feel* right? Or because I have evidence (or strong reasons) showing that MVCC will be too much burden? (**Yes!** it's true, CouchDB imposes disk space, disk i/o, and client burden) In my (jhs) experience, MVCC *feels* wrong but poses no problem in reality, *however*, for high-volume, no-history data, CouchDB is not ideal. Perhaps Redis or Membase? (Membase is planned to be CouchDB compatibile in the future via Couchbase.)

Comment: @jhs CouchDB `versions` are not for history, they are for replication control. If you have *no history* data then there will never be more than 1 version ever in CouchDB. You are correct that worrying about performance without profiling is a premature optimization. I my experience CouchDB is **awesome** for *no history* data like log file entries. It writes fast, it reads fast and with the full text indexing it queries fast.

Comment: @Jarrod Strictly, from my reading up, its for MVCC ie: concurrency control. By never overwriting an existing record, always appending data to the db files, you can drop locking and transactions primarily, and the rev-id works for replication/save conflicts too.

Answer (score 4):

You may try _revs_limit API (e.g. /database/_revs_limit). I have never used it I just read about it on this link http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview

Comment: That is a very clever suggestion, however I would guess that setting the limit to 0 would not work, and if you set it to 1 or greater, CouchDB will still require the `_rev` field, so you still have to do fetch/modify/store. Perhaps it's worth a try though!

Answer (score 0):

[Couchbase single server 2.0 developer preview](http://www.couchbase.org/products/couchbase-single/2-0-series) has automatic compaction among other features and improvements [which should be also present](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/6604616916/couchbase-single-server-important-improvements) in the future versions of CouchDB as well. This can help you to get rid of older document versions automatically based on some settings.